# how to apply single page checkout using drupal ubercart

Tags: ubercart, 7

I am using Drupal6 with ubercart.I want to apply single page checkout instead of multi step checkout. When I checked the ubercart features it provide the one page checkout in features lint but  I am not getting idea how to use this feature.Is there  any module for it?

I have a package functionality in my site.There are three package silver,gold and standard.I want user can choose only one package at a time and user should be not able to add more package in cart if the package is already in cart and if user has already that package?

Please help waiting for the response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: single page checkout means only 1 item in cart ?

Comment: thanks or the response. single page checkout mean onepagecheckout process for users

Answer (score 1):

Yo cant make it single page. Mandatory steps are,

1. Add product to cart
2. Go to checkout page
3. Payment

You can combine the steps 3 by adding Shipping and billing address using [Ubercart Checkout Tweaks](http://drupal.org/project/uc_checkout_tweaks) module, which helps to

**Assume billing and delivery addresses will be the same**

> In many stores, orders are delivered to the billing address more times
>   than not. Enabling this option in the checkout settings will default
>   the "same address" checkbox at checkout, making the checkout page seem
>   shorter and less intimidating.

For limit the products that added to cart you can use [`hook_add_to_cart`](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_add_to_cart)

```
Parameters:
$nid - the node ID of the product
$qty - the quantity being added
$data - the data array, including attributes and model number adjustments
```

Comment: Thanks Nikhil.Can you give me idea about : I have a package functionality in my site.There are three package silver,gold and standard.I want user can choose only one package at a time and user should be not able to add more package in cart if the package is already in cart and if user has already that package? I mean user can add only one package add a time.

Comment: @RajeevSharma How do you maintain package functionality ?

Comment: by using ubercart i have created three products silver,golden,standard(Packages).Please give me better idea about this functionlality

Comment: @RajeevSharma Only 3 products? Or is it like a category ?

Comment: only 3 products

Comment: @RajeevSharma See my Edit.